# How to seperate dictionaries that are not comma separated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

I have a text file which contains dictionaries that are not comma sepearated in the following format:

{} {} {}

Example

```
{
    'header': 'sdf',
    'meta': {
        'searchId': {
            'searchId': 1234
        },
        'timestamp': 1234,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
} 
{
    'header': 'sdf',
        'timestamp': 14,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
}
```

These dictionaries may contain nested dictionaries. I want to read this file and turn it into a list of dictionaries i.e. in the format [{},{},{}]
Example

```
[{
    'header': 'sdf',
    'meta': {
        'searchId': {
            'searchId': 1234
        },
        'timestamp': 1234,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
}, 
{
    'header': 'sdf',
        'timestamp': 14,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
}]
```

Can someone suggest a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: what created this data? why not use an existing serialization format?

Comment: Basically I am supplied with data which is in this format. Who created it is not important as it will not be serialized

Comment: There isn't really a standard way to deserialize data in this sort of format. If you want to do it in a robust way, you're going to need to write your own parser.

Comment: No, see, that's the problem. It *is* serialized (there are no "dicts" in the file, it is *only text*), someone made the bad decision of dumping the string representation of a dictionary into a file would suffice as serialization. Now,  you have to parse this manually. This can be avoided by using a proper, well supported serialization format (JSON being obvious here). The *best* solution is to fix the source

Comment: Will all strings never contain space characters ?

Comment: This is a formatted view of a dictionary. Strings will contain white spaces

Comment: Did you see that even the string representation is corrupted ? I mean, some closing brackets are simply missing... And not unequivocally guessable.

Comment: Some missing closing brackets might be my error trying to delete the sensistive information but rest assured the string is not corrupted

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Given the sample "text" in the question there are actually 2 valid Python dicts that can be properly parsed as statements by `ast.parse`. You can see my AST-based answer for a robust solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two other answers assume that the dicts in your data file are on separate lines so that each dict can be parsed as valid Python statements. If that is not the case, however, you can use `lib2to3` and modify the Python grammar in [Grammar.txt](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/lib2to3/Grammar.txt) so that a simple statement (denoted by `simple_stmt` in the grammar file) does not have to end with a newline character:

```
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, refactor, pygram, pgen2
from io import StringIO
from functools import partialmethod
with open(pygram._GRAMMAR_FILE) as file:
    grammar = StringIO(''.join(line.replace(' NEWLINE', '') if line.startswith('simple_stmt:') else line for line in file))
pgen2.pgen.ParserGenerator.__init__ = partialmethod(pgen2.pgen.ParserGenerator.__init__, stream=grammar)
pygram.python_grammar = pgen2.pgen.generate_grammar()
```

and look for `atom` nodes at the top level (whose parent node does not have a parent) instead:

```
class ScrapeAtoms(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    PATTERN = "atom"

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.nodes = []

    def transform(self, node, results):
        if not node.parent.parent:
            self.nodes.append(node)
        return node

class Refactor(refactor.RefactoringTool):
    def get_fixers(self):
        self.scraper = ScrapeAtoms(None, None)
        return [self.scraper], []

    def get_result(self):
        return '[%s]\n' % ',\n'.join(str(node).rstrip() for node in self.scraper.nodes)
```

so that:

```
s = '''{'a': {1: 2}}{'b': 2}{
  'c': 3
}{'d': 4}'''
refactor = Refactor(None)
refactor.refactor_string(s, '')
print(refactor.get_result())
```

outputs:

```
[{'a': {1: 2}},
{'b': 2},
{
  'c': 3
},
{'d': 4}]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/CompleteStarchyFactorial

Answer (score 0):

Like others have stated in the comments. This isn't `json` data. You merely have multiple string representations of dicts pretty printed to the file in succession, and you're also missing a closing bracket in the first one.

So I suggest looping through the file and build a string for each dict then you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse the string into a dict. Something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

current = ''
data = []

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('{'):
            current = line
        elif line.startswith('}'):
            data.append(literal_eval(current + line))
        else:
            current += line
```

Results in `data` *(using `pprint`)*:

```
[{'header': 'sdf',
  'meta': {'attachments': ['ABC'],
           'searchId': {'searchId': 1234},
           'timestamp': 1234,
           'xmlData': {'release': None, 'version': None}}},
 {'attachments': ['ABC'],
  'header': 'sdf',
  'timestamp': 14,
  'xmlData': {'release': None, 'version': None}}]
```

After this you should overwrite the data, And never use this as serialization again. This is why there's libraries for this.

Comment: It pretty much solves the issue IF the data is pretty printed else it fails. I guess the the only feasible to this problem would be to convert the data into pretty printed format and  then proceed because to undertake the data in it's raw form would require the use of a parser

Comment: @bhanugoyal if you have control over how the data is received *why do this in the first place*? Just use a real serialization format.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I dont have control over the source data. All I can do is format it in a more readable way.

Answer (score 0):

Since each dict in the file is a valid Python statement, a more robust solution would be to use the `lib2to3` to parse the file as Python code and extract the statement nodes so that you can enclose them in square brackets, separated by commas:

```
from lib2to3 import fixer_base, refactor

class ScrapeStatements(fixer_base.BaseFix):
    PATTERN = "simple_stmt"

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.nodes = []

    def transform(self, node, results):
        self.nodes.append(node)
        return node

class Refactor(refactor.RefactoringTool):
    def get_fixers(self):
        self.scraper = ScrapeStatements(None, None)
        return [self.scraper], []

    def get_result(self):
        return '[%s]\n' % ',\n'.join(str(node).rstrip() for node in self.scraper.nodes)
```

so that:

```
s = '''{
    'header': 'sdf',
    'meta': {
        'searchId': {
            'searchId': 1234
        },
        'timestamp': 1234,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
    }
}
{
    'header': 'sdf',
        'timestamp': 14,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
}
'''

refactor = Refactor(None)
refactor.refactor_string(s, '')
print(refactor.get_result())
```

outputs:

```
[{
    'header': 'sdf',
    'meta': {
        'searchId': {
            'searchId': 1234
        },
        'timestamp': 1234,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
    }
},
{
    'header': 'sdf',
        'timestamp': 14,
        'attachments': [
            'ABC'
        ],
        'xmlData': {
            'release': None,
            'version': None,
        }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the dicts in the file are on separate lines as they are in your sample input, then each dict by itself is a valid Python statement, so you can use `ast.parse` to parse the file into an abstract syntax tree, look for the expression nodes (of type `Expr`), and build a new `Expression` node with a `List` node to hold all the aforementioned `Expr` nodes. The new `Expression` node can then be compiled and evaluated as an actual Python list of dicts, so that given your sample input data in variable `s`:

```
import ast

tree = ast.parse(s)
exprs = [node.value for node in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(node, ast.Expr)]
new = ast.Expression(body=ast.List(elts=exprs, ctx=ast.Load()))
ast.fix_missing_locations(new)
lst = eval(compile(new, '', 'eval'))
```

`lst` would become:

```
[{'header': 'sdf',
  'meta': {'searchId': {'searchId': 1234},
           'timestamp': 1234,
           'attachments': ['ABC'],
           'xmlData': {'release': None, 'version': None}}},
 {'header': 'sdf',
  'timestamp': 14,
  'attachments': ['ABC'],
  'xmlData': {'release': None, 'version': None}}]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/FocusedCylindricalTypes